# Does levedb support key-only iteration?

Tags: go, leveldb

I'm using [goleveldb](https://github.com/syndtr/goleveldb) which is an implementation of leveldb in Go and I need to iterate over keys with a prefix. It supports prefix-iteration but when iterating over keys, it seems that the values are also fetched under the hood. This leads to a huge performance drawback when dealing with a big database. From the documentations and code I didn't find a way to iterate over keys without fetching values neither in Go implementation nor in [original C++ implementation](https://github.com/google/leveldb). If there is a way to do so, I would appreciate someone helping me to get in the right direction.

Comment: You can either duplicate keys with minimal value just for iteration or look for something like badger https://blog.dgraph.io/post/badger/

Comment: @ren Thanks for your reply. The values in my case could get too big, so duplicating keys with minimal values would result in a huge key set and hence slow lookups. I've tried Badger and it's very fast when it comes to key-only iteration, but it has other issues like too much memory consumption and it also doesn't support snappy compression (which is working wonderful in leveldb for my data)